# Which countries are friends/allies in Middle East?

Tags: international-relations, middle-east

In the latest news about the murder of a journalist it was hinted that Turkey and Saudi Arabia are not friends. I knew Saudi Arabia and Iran are not friends either, nor are Turkey and Iran, or Iran and Iraq, or Iraq and Saudi Arabia, not to mention Israel.

So I wonder what are some of the friendships/alliances between Middle Eastern countries?

Comment: SA and UAE are bffs. Iran has good relations with Syria,Hezbollah in Lebanon (the government is closer to SA and the Houthis in Yemen. Turkey is growing closer to Qatar, and SA is attempting to build stronger ties with Israel.

Comment: May be worth putting the year in the question ! :)

Comment: Have you looked at map of the region? Because last time I did, France and Italy were very definitely not part of middle east.

Comment: @Miech I was just giving an example of what friendship/alliance means.

Comment: Something like friendship doesn´t really exist in politics, it´s all about interests, so the question is a bit incorect.

Answer (score 9):

The general guidelines for who are and aren't friends in the middle east follow the [Iran-Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Saudi_Arabia_proxy_conflict) struggle for dominance in the region, often carried out through proxy. This often also manifests itself as a sunni-shia conflict, though whether sectarian violence is really a result of geopolitical interest  needs to be taken on a case-by-case basis.
A general breakdown of the sides in the Iran-KSA conflict are as follows, and the friendships/alliances in the region generally follow this.

Iran:

- Syria
- Houthis (Iranian proxy in Yemen)
- Hezbollah (Iranian proxy in
  Lebanon) and to a lesser extent Lebanon itself
- Iraq
- Turkey

KSA:

- Gulf Cooperation Council

  - Kuwait
  - Bahrain
  - Qatar ([historically but not recently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9318_Qatar_diplomatic_crisis))
  - UAE
  - Oman
- Egypt
- Yemen
- Jordan (historically more so than today)

Mixed:

- Lebanon
- Afghanistan

Both countries voice support for Palestine and condemn Israel, but KSA puportedly has [under-the-table relations with Israel](https://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Senior-IDF-officer-to-Saudi-paper-Israel-is-Mideasts-island-of-stability-439493) focused on countering Iranian influence in the region

Comment: Also worth to be considered that Egypt is becoming more ambivalent. Not exactly becoming closer with Iran, but they are getting stronger ties with russians.